# Ascensor.js not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got to make a single page website for a client of mine, and the Ascensor.js plugin seems to do everything I need it to do. However, I cant for the life of me get it working.

http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#/Home

Originally I was trying to get it working within a WordPress theme but I gave up and tried to just get it working exactly as the example on the website, no joy.

Heres the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.ascensor.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>

$('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
AscensorName:'ascensor',
ChildType:'section',
AscensorFloorName:'Home | Implementation | HTML',
Time:1000,
WindowsOn:1,
Direction:'chocolate',
AscensorMap:'2|1 & 2|2 & 3|2',
Easing:'easeInOutQuad',
KeyNavigation:true,
Queued:false,

});

</script>

<div id="ascensorBuilding">
    <section>
        <article class="container_12">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section>
        <article class="container_12">
            <h1>About</h1>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section>
        <article class="container_12">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This really should be working as i've followed the example exactly. Ive tried it with and without the classes on the article elements (I think the plugin is supposed to create these). Has anyone got experience with this plugin that can give me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have to include jQuery migration plugin http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js jQuery 1.9.0 has removed lot of deprecated method from 1.8.x release so some of the third party plugins may not work. For backward compatibility jquery has provided the migration plugin

Answer (score 1):

First you need to wrap you code with jQuery.ready

```
$(function(){
    $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
        AscensorName:'ascensor',
        ChildType:'section',
        AscensorFloorName:'Home | Implementation | HTML',
        Time:1000,
        WindowsOn:1,
        Direction:'chocolate',
        AscensorMap:'2|1 & 2|2 & 3|2',
        Easing:'easeInOutQuad',
        KeyNavigation:true,
        Queued:false,
    });
});
```

You are missing both [migration plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js) and [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ufDgu/1/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that originally and it still didn't work so I assumed it was wrong. Seems to be working to an extent now (generates the correct layout and spacing) but I cant get the previous and next links to work.

It does seem detect the link clicks and I can see it working in the URL, but the window stays in place and does not move.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving here a simple work I'm doing using ascensor.
Feel free to grab all the code you want.
Just remember to set "overflow:auto" to your "section" tag in css AND "overflow:hidden" to the div you use for your building, #house in my case.

http://www.thegrowth.eu/mari/index.php

The version of the plugin I'm using doesn't work on current jQuery version unless you hack the code.
Stick to version 1.8.3, you can grab it from my site.
Also, you will need nothing else but jQuery-UI to use some of ascensor's easing features and such.

And forgive my English :p