# How to solve my jquery plugin issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a Jquery plugin called ancesor

I have something like the following:

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation '>
    <ul class='alinks list-inline links-to-floor'>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#'>link1</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#'>link2</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#'>link3</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#'>link4</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#'>link5</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>

<div id='ascensorBuilding'>
        <div class='ascensorFloor1'  >
            test here
        </div>
        <div class='ascensorFloor2'  >
           blog hree oooo
        </div>
        <div class='ascensorFloor3'  >
            aaagg
        </div>
        <div class='ascensorFloor4'  >
            dddd
        </div>
        <div class='ascensorFloor5'  >
            ddd
        </div>
</div>



    <script src="/includes/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/includes/lib/jquery.ascensor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/includes/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
             var ascensor = $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
           AscensorName: 'ascensor',
                   ChildType: 'div',
                   AscensorFloorName: '1.0 | 1.1 | 1.3 | 4.3 | 5.4 | 5.5 | 5.6 | 7.6 | 8.6 |    8.7 | 8.8 | 8.9 | 10.2',
                   Time: 9000,
                   WindowsOn: 1,
                   Direction: "chocolate",
                   AscensorMap: '1|1 & 2|1 & 3|1 & 3|2 & 3|3 & 4|3 & 5|3 & 3|4 & 3|5 & 4|5 & 5|5 & 6|5 & 3|6',
                   Easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
                   KeyNavigation: true,
                   Queued: false,
                   QueuedDirection: "y"
            })

             $(".alinks li").click(function(event, index) {
                ascensor.trigger("scrollToStage", $(this).index());
            });
```

My webpage doesn't seem to apply the parameters I pass. For example, the duration is never 9000 and the page only shifted vertically. Can someone help me about this issue? Thanks a lot!

plugin page.
http://jque.re/plugins/image-galleries-decks/ascensor/#/HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are specifying the `Easing` option, but you are not including the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/), which is required to support that option. I got this idea from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747486/859640).

It seems to work once that library is included: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNs6t/)

Without the jQuery UI library included, the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```